# How to edit metadata of an uploaded file to mediawiki?

Tags: image, upload, mediawiki, wikipedia

I am using a extension with mediawiki that uses the metadata of the uploaded file to generate its title.

However I cannot see how to edit the metadata for an uploaded file in mediawiki at all.

Here is the documention for the extention:

> CategoryGallery with captions generated from image description files
>   (requires CategoryGallery extension) You'll need
>   Extension:CategoryGallery for this. Place image descriptions on your
>   image file pages (e.g. File:Popsicle stick Eiffel Tower.jpg) using the
>   same PageSummary template as before. Now, on the page where you're
>   putting the gallery, use e.g.:
>
> `<catgallery cat="Aubry" bpdcaption="short_summary" />`
>
> The result is as
>   follows (note how the captions are generated using the metadata you
>   saved on each image page):

How can I do this? Here is an example of the files I have uplaoded: http://www.gwart.co.uk/File:Eldar_Avatar_-_Mark_Gibbons_1994.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about metadata generated by CommonsMetadata, see [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CommonsMetadata/info_template_for_3rd-party_wikis). There is also metadata extracted from the file; you can't edit that, short of editing the file itself.